# Play 2.0 Evolution for datomic

Tags: java, playframework, database-migration, datomic, playframework-evolutions

I am using `Play 2.0 framework` and `Datomic` for persistence. As of now, we usually install the database (and run migrations ) manually i.e. by reading schema from `*.edn` files from groovy script.

Now, I want to move my migration to 'Evolution', what could be the best possible way to do it? So all I want to know is:

1. How to setup evolution for nosql databases (or persistence)
2. How to write the scripts?
3. How to run evolution for these databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it won't be possible to use evolutions **through** `Datomic`, they're meant to be used with JDBC/SQL (as evidenced by the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/java/play/db/evolutions/Evolution.java)). That being said, It's possible in theory to achieve this if you were using an SQL database as the storage service for datomic (but from your question i gather that you're not).

A solution/alternative could be to call your Groovy script (or do it in Java) from within Play's `onStart` method which can be overriden in Global.java (example [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaGlobal)). Of course, you would have to do the checks to validate that the schema is up-to-date your self.